# Faulty Mouse Point Detection?

Tags: java, graphics2d, mouselistener

Hey :) So I'm making buttons for a game I'm making. The graphics work, at least to the extent that I don't have to fix them yet. However, click detection is a bit iffy. For example pressing where the black line is in the first picture below, triggers a response. Now obviously that point is not on the button. I have tested the buttons bounding box by drawing a rectangle around it, using it's getBounds() method (which is also used for click detection) and it draws a perfect rectangle around it. So then I tested the mouse click points and it turns out that even though the button is placed at y = 100, at the black line, the mouse point is also equal to 100... Now I have no idea why that is happening, especially because, if I place the button in the top left corner, the mouse detection correctly detects the top pixels and there is no offset...

[image: Weird Mouse Detection]

Comment: Just a guess here, but the rendered graphics may be scaled. This could result in the physical location being inside the box, but all graphical components saying otherwise. For example, doing a half-scale, a point rendered (500, 500) would be visually at (250, 250).

Comment: Is the button scaled or translated? Have you tried drawing something to the position of the mouse on the screen? btw I <3 Sacred Stones :)

Comment: @Obicere Yeah, the button is scaled, but so is it's bounding box. I tested that by wrapping the button with its bounding box which resulted in a rectangle that perfectly fit the button. I also did not resize the frame, but I will check anyways, thanks :)

Comment: @AnubianNoob Sacred Stones is a great game <3 And that series is what this game will be similar to ;) And check the comment above this one, I answered the question.

Comment: Do you have a link or github repo?

Comment: @StrongJoshua that's the problem though, that rectangle you drew would also be scaled. Try drawing the (x,y) coordinate of the mouse, say by filling an oval: (x-3, y-3, 6, 6).

Comment: @AnubianNoob Here is the src: http://www.mediafire.com/download/j0egm20ruoh3fjw/Temp._Src.zip

Comment: @Obicere Ok, you're right, there is some scaling going on, since the oval shifts further down and to the right as I get closer to the bottom right corner of the frame. Now I just need to find where this is happening, thanks :).

Comment: @StrongJoshua - I think both your question and summary/answer are good, but just wanted to mention given the title _Faulty Mouse Point Detection?_ that you should never assume "The System" is broken unless you have eliminated all possibility that there is a bug in your code or that you don't fully understand the system.  Your Q/A is useful in that it will help other people understand the expected system behavior, but the title implies that you think the system is not working correctly.

Comment: @StephenP I admit it does, but I also admit that that was almost what I had suspected at the start. However, anyone that is unable to solve this immediately, like I was, will likely also think it is the systems fault and might Google search something similar to my title, so hopefully this misleading title will actually direct the best possible attention.

Comment: @StrongJoshua - Granted, and that's why I upvoted the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out that there was some scaling going on with the frame, however I have no idea where it came from. I prepped the game to be scalable so I did all the painting to the optimal size BufferedImage and then I scale that image to the frame. However, even when I removed that the mouse location was still offset. In the end I overcame it by finishing the scaling optimization which required finding the scale of the frame by dividing the current width and height by the optimal width and height. And then dividing the mouse location by that value.
I just figured this out. Setting the size of a component and packing the frame after adding the component, results in the actual frame being that size (counting the border), yet when you retrieve the size of the frame, it disregards the border... Why does this happen?

## **Solved**

When I did the game screen scaling, I used the actual frame's height and width to scale the screen, instead of the canvas's height and width. I changed that and now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

This is rather interesting, and during my times in have had similar problems. This all really depends on why the Mouse Listener is attached to. Many people attach the listener to the frame, but draw on a panel. This can have the effects you are describing so it is usually better to either draw directly onto the frame, or attach the listener to the panel. In 99.99% of cases, I would always choose the latter. Really, no one should ever choose the latter UNLESS it's something very small.

Panels are exactly that; they're boxes which hold things, hence 'panel'. In my experiences it has always been more effective to use a panel. Frames are just the container to hold multiple panels.

Hope I could help, report your findings in a comment and/or post update.

Jarod.

Comment: I add the MouseListener to the canvas which is in the frame. And you meant "former" the second time you said "latter", correct?

Comment: Did I? I'm sorry. I meant the latter. You should always use panels in almost every instance if swing. They're pretty much your main goto point for swing. This includes attaching the mouse listener to it.

Answer (score 0):

Got bored so I whipped up an example of what I *think* is going on.

In essence, I do full rendering to a buffer (BufferedImage here). And then draw the render to the canvas. This may or may not be what you do, but I did it merely for example.

Seeing as you did say that it works fine in the top-left corner, I came to the hypothesis that scaling is the issue, since the x,y-values near the top left approach 0, and `0 * scale = 0`, even a scaling of 1000 won't have any offset. The issue is when those components are *not* at the top-left corner, which you demonstrated for us.

Hopefully this answers your question. As for solving it, you can either accommodate for scaling, or use a [letterboxing technique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letterboxing_%28filming%29). Beyond those two, there are certainly many other ways to deal with this (such as fixing the screen size).

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

/**
 * @author Obicere
 */
public class GraphicScale {

    public GraphicScale(){
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Graphic Scale Example");
        final MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();

        final Timer repaintTimer = new Timer(50, e -> frame.repaint());

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        repaintTimer.start();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(GraphicScale::new);
    }

    public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

        private final Rectangle box = new Rectangle(100, 100, 100, 50);
        private final Dimension size = new Dimension(500, 500);
        private final BufferedImage render = new BufferedImage(500, 500, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(final Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);

            render.flush();
            render();
            g.drawImage(render, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this); // Trick is that this gets rescaled!
        }

        public void render(){
            final Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) render.getGraphics();
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, render.getWidth(), render.getHeight());

            final Point mouse = getMousePosition();
            if(mouse != null){
                if(box.contains(mouse)) {
                    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    g.fill(box);
                }
                g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                g.drawOval(mouse.x - 3, mouse.y - 3, 6, 6);
            }
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.draw(box);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
            return size;
        }
    }
}
```